# Splash Screen Image gets squashed on S4

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building a Hybrid app using Cordova.

I have placed different sized splash images in the res drawable folders and It works fine in all major devices but it gets squashed on Samsung Galaxy S4. Any fix to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add 640 × 1136 image (splash screen) to res-> drawable-xhdpi folder in your phonegap android project, i think thats solve your problem,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what dimensions for icon file?

Answer (score 2):

Galaxy S4 comes under xxhdpi. So you need to put splash image in res-> drawable-xxhdpi folder.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung galaxy S4 comes under large screen size. 1080 x 1920 image to res-> drawable-xhdpi

Answer (score 1):

if you want that your app works fine on modern devices such as Galaxy Nexus, Nuxus 4, etc you should support xhdpi screens.

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp (hdpi)
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp (xhdpi)

Answer (score 0):

Check the phone model before load the image. And if it is Galaxy S4, load a proper image for it.